# Firebase child_changed with equalTo

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get changes for certain items in my list -- not all items as this is a huge list that could be modified by many people.

```
const ref = firebase.database()
                    .ref('images')
                    .orderByValue('place')
                    .equalTo('san-francisco')

ref.on('child_changed', data => {
  console.log(data)
})
```

If I take out `equalTo` it works, but it will get data for every city whereas I'm only concerned about one.

Comment: You are missing a quote at the end of the city name: `.equalTo('san-francisco')`

Comment: Thanks, but it was only a typo on sample code to make things simpler to read - in real-life I pass in a variable.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the variable you pass in to use for the equalTo() function contains a value that exists for the "place" key in your dataset?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `orderByChild` instead of `orderByValue`

Comment: That did not work either...  I wonder if this is just a bug with https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase . Thanks for your input.